# Product page and category page disappeared

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, category, production-mode

Developed on developer mode and everything is OK, just set production mode, home page and admin panel is OK but category page completely disappeared and shows a blank page and also product page is gone and just shows description title.
what should I do? use Magento 2.1.

Comment: Have you check consol and log file?

Comment: there is no log in var/log of magento

Comment: turn on error enable

Comment: how should i do it?